# Separating arguments to a function, in locales with comma as decimal marker

Tags: function, localization, numbers

In locales, e.g. French, with comma as decimal indicator (where "5,2" means five and two-tenths), how do users separate function arguments from each other?

For example, in many programming/scripting languages, I could specify MAX(1.5, X) in an EN-US locale. How do you avoid the ambiguity between the comma as decimal indicator, and as argument separator?

In particular, I'm interested in how software that's perceived as user-friendly in the foreign locale does it. Obviously, it's a no-brainer to say, "though shalt use decimal POINTs", but that's not particularly "friendly".

Comment: Check this question as it in someway talks about this same situation... http://stackoverflow.com/q/5861209/114029

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We struck this exact problem when putting together queries for our product using DB2.

We had a query along the lines of:

```
select fn (COLUMN_NAME,5.2) from TABLE_NAME
```

and the `5.2` was actually inserted dynamically by our software, based on a user selection (forget about injection attacks for now, they were prevented via another means).

In locales where "five and two tenths" was written as `5,2` (darn those Europeans), we ended up with:

```
select fn (COLUMN_NAME,5,2) from TABLE_NAME
```

which DB2 complained about bitterly.

The IBM-given solution was to ensure that *separator* commas had spaces on either side and *decimal* commas did not:

```
select fn (COLUMN_NAME , 5,2) from TABLE_NAME
```

But you'll find that many languages solve this problem in *exactly* the non-friendly way you mention.

None of the ISO C-like standards (well, none that I know of, anyway) allow a constant number to be declared as `5,2`, despite the fact that ISO is very much an "internationalised" organisation.

They also don't require that keywords like `if`, `while` and `for` be localised into Arabic, or Mongolian, or Klingon, which would lead to code such as:

```cc
chugh (rIn)
    nobHa';
```

Comment: I feel like if I follow this answer, my existing code probably already behaves like that. e.g. if someone entered "hypot(1,2 , 3,4)" the way the parser works would already separate the tokens at the comma. So I'm assuming SQL works this way for the same reason. I was wondering whether users in European countries which use the comma would actually be happy with that, or whether they use a different separator. For instance, in the case of CSV files, I have heard that some countries use semicolons for cell separators.

Comment: @Hakanai, that depends entirely on what's doing the parsing. For example, ISO C would see this a a `hypot` function taking four arguments, regardless of your locale. DB2 sees it as two arguments (1.2 and 3.4) or four arguments (1, 2, 3, and 4) depending on locale.

Comment: Yeah, I realise this, but I wonder whether that actually equates to the users in those regions thinking it perfectly reasonable to have to input it like that.