# jQuery UI Slider and jQuery Globalization with value delimited by comma [ , ]

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, localization, numbers, jquery-globalization, jquery-slider

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC 3 app that uses both [jQuery Globalization](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-global) and [jQuery UI Slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/).

I'm localizing this app to Portuguese from Brazil (pt-BR) and it also supports English.

The problem is that when I change the language to Portuguese, all Model `float` values come delimited by a comma ( , ) like 7,7. I then try to set the Slider initial value but it only accepts the value with a dot ( . ) like 7.7.

To overcome such situation I'm doing this:

```
$.CreateSlider("#sliderHeight", "#Height", @Model.Height.FormatValue(), 0, 2.5, 0.01);
```

FormatValue is an extension method:

```
public static string FormatValue(this float value)
{
    return value.Value.ToString().Replace(",", ".");
}
```

You see that I have to replace the comma delimiter with a dot delimiter so that I can set the jQuery Slider value.

I then have to use jQuery Globalization to show the correct value in the UI this way:

```
$(textBox).val($.global.format(ui.value, 'n2'));
```

It works at least...

My question is:

Is there a better or standard way of doing this?

The thing is that the Model values are coming the way they should, that is, as I switched the culture to pt-BR the numbers come ( , ) delimited. This is correct in my point of view. The limitation is in the way the jQuery Slider receives the value.

Just to complement: if I tried to pass the values the way they come from the `@Model`, I'd have something like this, that obviously would break (because the parameters values are themselves separated by commas):

```
$.CreateSlider("#sliderHeight", "#Height", 7,7 , 0, 2.5, 0.01);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your slider accepts InvariantCulture values, so you need to provide such. Just modify your method:

```
public static string ParseValue(this float value)
{
    return value.Value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

BTW. ParseValue is not the best name here as no parsing going on. FormatValue would sound better.
BTW. Your original method won't work correctly for some cultures (might not be visible for small values but for greater than i.e. 100 bad things could happen). If you need a dot as floating point, always use InvariantCulture.

Comment: ł: Thanks for letting me know about the `ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`. It worked. I also thought about the greater values you mentioned and the problem that could arise. About the method name: I changed it. I didn't notice the name I had given to the method because I was trying to make this code work. :D